# Why Jekyll don´t render the Markdown File on Homepage?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I want to display the content of an markdown file on my homepage, build with the static site generator jekyll. But jekyll dont render the markdown. Anybody an idea what i make wrong? Result:

[image]

**Code index.html**

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="home">

  {% include index.md %}

</div>
```

**Code _includes/default.html**

```
<div class="page-content">
      <div class="wrapper">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Code _includes/index.md**

```
---
layout: default
title: Home
permalink: /
---

This is the base Jekyll theme. You can find out more info about customizing your Jekyll theme, as well as basic Jekyll usage documentation at [jekyllrb.com](http://jekyllrb.com/)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, includes are not supposed to have front matter. **Remove it** from `_includes/index.html`. This must now read as :

```
This is the base Jekyll theme. You can find out more info about customizing your Jekyll theme, as well as basic Jekyll usage documentation at [jekyllrb.com](http://jekyllrb.com/)
```

Including markdown file from an html post/page is not working straight.

In order to include a `.md` file from an `.html` one, you need to `capture`, then `markdownify`.

```
---
layout: default
---
<div class="home">
  {% capture index %}{% include index.md %}{% endcapture %}
  {{ index | markdownify }}    
</div>
```